# Persist Google Cardboard forward direction across scene loads in Unity3D 4.6.7?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm having trouble trying to maintain what Google Cardboard considers forward for the device after a scene load.  Although I can't find any obvious call to this in the SDK c# code, it appears that the Google Cardboard SDK will automatically call Recenter after each scene load.  I've tried calling DontDestroyOnLoad on the cardboard instantiated prefab, and on the Cardboard.SDK object (which is mentioned on line 328 of Cardboard.cs).  This persists those objects across the load, but the view is still re-centered based on the current orientation of the device.

I want to avoid the recenter because some of the gaze-based menu items that can initiate a load are off to the user's left or right - which then makes the new center be to the left/right after the scene load.  The user then has to physically move their body to be facing towards the new forward.

Is anyone else attempting the same thing?  Am I missing something obvious?

Any suggestions very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function Cardboard.OnLevelWasLoaded() calls device.Reset(), which in the base class implementation just calls Recenter(), which has the effect you are seeing.  If you comment out that line, or guard it with a variable you can control, the facing should not reset.

Comment: Wow - I've looked at that file a dozen times and have other edits there, and completely missed seeing it.  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @smd Is this the same case in Unity 5? I've commented out the specific lines like you said, but when I play in the editor, the positions still reset.

Comment: The editor is handled by a fake device script in the Scripts/VRDevices directory.  It uses local state to model the current head orientation.  Loading a new scene causes a new device object to get created, which rezeroes them.  Try changing the variables mouseX, mouseY and mouseZ to be static -- that might fix the issue for you.  (Leave the Recenter() line commented out as well...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but on Gear VR (Unity 5). In case anyone else is looking for this, I've answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481563/how-to-prevent-automatic-re-centering-when-scene-is-loaded-on-gear-vr).

Briefly, if you're also using OVR Utilities from Oculus:

1. Locate the OVR Manager script attached to the OVRCameraRig
2. Uncheck 'Reset Tracker On Load'