# How to prevent automatic re-centering when scene is loaded on Gear VR?

Tags: rotation, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I'm using Unity 5 and OVR utilities, I'd like to avoid the scene being recentered every time I load a new scene. Basically, I'd like the player to be able to sit down and even if he's looking at his right at the moment of a new scene loading, I'd like him to be able to continue playing without having to use some manual recentering or having to change his sitting position. 
I've found 2 other posts with the same question but only for other VR platforms and they didn't solve my problem:

[Persist Google Cardboard forward direction across scene loads in Unity3D 4.6.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395888/persist-google-cardboard-forward-direction-across-scene-loads-in-unity3d-4-6-7)

[Google Cardboard - how to face the same way when changing scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377894/google-cardboard-how-to-face-the-same-way-when-changing-scenes/37381671)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if you're using OVR Utilities from Oculus, there's a very simple boolean-based solution that you can set in the Editor:

1. Find the OVRManager script attached to the OVRCameraRig
2. Uncheck 'Reset Tracker On Load'